# Another Killer Robot on a Space Station or Space Ship Movie

Tags: story-identification, horror, space

I'll get this out of the way:
It's not Saturn 3.

It's not The Black Hole.

It's not Space Truckers.

The movie was released to home laserdisc before 1990.  I watched it at my dad's house before I moved across the country.
From my memory, the space station looked clean and polished, and there were 3 humans I can remember by the end of the movie, and a killer robot.  About 3/4 through the movie, the main heroes have a conversation with a scientist over the intercom, and they ask where the android is.  The scientist sounds rather creepy and way too calm with his replay "______ is with me."

When they go to the scientist, the a door opens and it is revealed that the scientist and the robot are now one being, basically 50/50 down the middle or so.

At least that's the recollection I have from 30 years ago now.

Any ideas aside from the 3 I listed as definitely not correct?

Thanks!

Comment: That bit with the intercom does sound like Saturn 3, but you've excluded that movie, so just making sure its not a mixture of a few movies. Are there any other story or location details, like when you say "a clean space station" any particular color scheme? Space station exterior design (hub with spokes or cylinder)? Anything about the actors (gender, race, age)? Costumes that stood out? Definitely in English as opposed to dubbed from another language?

Comment: Thanks for asking.  I excluded Saturn 3, because I just watched it, and it is not the movie I was thinking of.  The station/ship feels very white for the interior in my memory as opposed grey or silver.
The doctor/scientist that was "merged" with the robot was a male, adult, but I don't recall if was "old" as opposed to the rest of the station.  I do remember the movie started with several crew members, and I believe only a male and female survived at the end.  Typical, I know.  The robot was more human than what we had in Saturn 3.  I do not recall anything about the exterior of the ship.

Comment: As this sounds like a horror, any interesting or memorable deaths? Can you recall the setup for the visiting team (scientists, military, colonists) as why they are there or anything more about the killer robot? Humanoid/android (TNG Data, Alien's Bishop), covered in metal like C3PO, cyborg?

Comment: I cannot recall, tbh.  But it did leave me with a feeling of being terrified or mortified as a child.  The robot was all metal.  But human shaped.  It was a science station/ship.  I believe the doctor and robot lived there, and the visitors/team were going to discover something bad that he did, and he lost control of the robot.  unlike Saturn 3, the doctor was the older character and the rest of the characters seemed to be 20s/30s.  but no one seemed to be military

Comment: is it possible there were more robots than just the one?  Something like ["The Black Hole"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078869)?

Comment: I only remember the one.  the biggest identifier i can think of is the scene where the robot basically combines himself with the human scientist into a 50/50 creation.

Comment: I wonder if this could be Project Shadowchaser 3? Space station. Killer robot, there is a scene in which the robot appears to transform into a half human... It came out in 1995 I think so, is not an exact match for what you describe but take a look anyway... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0TDp9O77R8